# Check if page contains some text in PHP

Tags: php

I have weird issue. I am trying to get content of a web page (for example Google) and check if page contains some text. Sounds like a simple task, but I can't get it to work. Always getting FALSE after running script like this

```
$site_url = "http://google.com";
$site = file_get_contents( $site_url );
//echo $site;

$pos = stripos($site,"window.chrome");
var_dump( $pos );
```

Do you have some idea how to do search inside the page? And what is fast solution, because I need to put this in some loop?

Comment: 5 seconds reading the manual page for [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) would help

Comment: Is there anything in $site?

Comment: the whole page is in $site.

Comment: @Dagon, it was a typo error, fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.chrome` doesn't exist if you `echo $site` and do a find

My guess is when the browser loads, relevant javascript gets injected into the page and doing a `file_get_contents` doesn't trigger whatever does that

Comment: echo $site dumps me complete google page. When I go to view page source I can see window.chrome

Comment: Mine isn't showing that and neither is julesj apparently. This is what I see http://pastie.org/6644112

Comment: make sure you're viewing the source of your page, not googles

Comment: ok you are right. i tried with some other website and working.I have no idea how, but I see window.chrome in google code. Nvm will accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

Please check the content of `$site`. It doesn't contain 'window.chrome', so getting `false` as a result makes sense. You will get a position if you search for 'window.google'.

Comment: you are right. but when I go to page source for google page I can find window.chrome

Comment: how is that happening like that?

Comment: Google probably adds some JS based on your User Agent. This doesn't happen with the `file_get_contents` function.